# Xcode 10.2 Getting crashed while clicking on Xcode icon with 10.14.4 Beta (18E215a)

Tags: xcode, macos

I have just installed Xcode 10.2 and unfortunately, it's getting crashed. Even I haven't opened my project with it.

[image]
[image]

I have tried with deleting derived data caches and restart, but still no success.

Comment: Is this just launching xcode or opening a project of some sort?  Also, have you thought about moving up to the 10.14.5 beta?  10.14.4 was buggy for me.

Comment: Launching an Xcode. its working fine with other developers in my team

Comment: @RichardBarber, Thanks for your comments. It's working now. I have deleted Xcode, emptied my trash and tried again